# Specify the exact position of a kendo.ui.Popup

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to specify the left and top or X,Y position of the Popup Kendo menu?

As I can see from the official documentation 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/popup#configuration-position

it's only possible to specify some string parameters.

But I would like to specify the exact position (for example the position of the mouse click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by stepping into Kendo UI source code I've found that you can specify the exact position of the popup in the open method simply doing popup.open(x,y).

 [See this modified Kendo Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AJoQe/2)

 But it's not documented 

 [Kendo Popup Open documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/popup#methods-open)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the position of the popup via jQuery's `css` function in the `open` event.

```
open: function(event) {
    event.sender.element.css("top", "20px");
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use offset() and css() fucntions from jQuery as you suggest, but I have a random behaviour about the position of the popup menu. I've also tried to adjust the position before showing the menu and after, but with no luck.

Comment: @FrancescoAbbundo Can you create a fiddle, showing that behaviour?

Comment: I've solved by stepping into Kendo UI source code I've found that you can specify the exact position of the popup in the open method simply doing popup.open(x,y). But it's not documented  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/popup#methods-open